# point pattern packages and fitting integer in ppm

Tags: r, point, ppm, spatstat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncl7T.png)I ve been working with point pattern data and trying analyze it. I have few questions, I googled them but couldn't find a post with everything so this would be helpful for others as well.

1- what are the packages for point pattern? we all know {spatstat} but is there others?

2- I have marks in point pattern and if I want to fit it with ppm it won't fit the integer marks.("Currently, ppm will not fit models to a marked point pattern if the marks are not a factor.(An R Package for Analyzing Spatial Point Patterns by Dr Baddeley and Dr Turner)") so what we will do ?

3- in part 2, I assigned marks individually to use ppm(one factor mark each time) but what if I want to use them all together? I used mppm but didn't work. it says my variables aren't hyperframe and I also have one integer variable.

I ve been thinking it might be because of integer variable. I will take off and try again but I wanted to ask in here same time. So I can update it later if I can find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Please show in code your efforts in order to increase changes to get answet. A reproducible example in code is best.

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem and what you have done so far. What does your data look like and what does the integer mark represent?

Comment: I couldn't find how to add pic as a comment so I edited and added a pic. I showed one of my failure attempt. I couldn't find a way to run that mppm.

Comment: Well, the picture doesn't explain much. What kind of model are you trying to fit? Why is `mppm` relevant? What are your replicated point patterns? Etc... An important side note: `spatstat` works with Euclidean coordinates, so data in long,lat coordinates should always be projected before doing any analysis. Depending on where you are on the globe the error from using long,lat without projection varies, but it can be extremely misleading close to the poles.